# What trait bound can be used to match all unsigned integer types in Rust?

Tags: rust, integer, traits

I want to define trait bound for a generic function over all unsigned integer types in rust. Function signature as below:

```
fn process_unsigned<T: UnsignedInt>(param: T) -> T {
    if param meets condition {
        // process and return result as T
    }
    else {
        return 0; // has to meet the trait bound on T
    }
}
```

What is the appropriate bound for T?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rust offers the [`num`](https://docs.rs/num/latest/num/) crate with abstractive traits over Rust's numeric types. You could try using the [`num::Unsigned`](https://docs.rs/num/latest/num/trait.Unsigned.html) trait for `T`.